# Getting the jpg images from an HTML file

Tags: parsing, grep, html-parsing

I'm trying to use grep to get the full url addresses of jpg images in an HTML file. One problem is that there aren't many newlines in it, so when I use grep it gets the path, but also a lot of other stuff I'm not interested in. How can I just get the urls for the jpg images?

Comment: Can you provide an example of your HTML and your current `grep` command?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**One single `sed` command**

```
sed -n '/<img/s/.*src="\([^"]*\)".*/\1/p' yourfile.html
```

<sub>or using [ERE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#POSIX_basic_and_extended) ([extended regular expressions](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/BRE-vs-ERE.html#BRE-vs-ERE)) to avoid [backslashes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backslash) from above expression:</sub>

```
sed -E -n '/<img/s/.*src="([^"]*)".*/\1/p' yourfile.html
```

**One basic `grep` command**

```
grep -o '<img[^>]*src="[^"]*"' yourfile.html
```

**Two successive basic `grep` commands**

```
grep -o '<img[^>]*src="[^"]*"' yourfile.html | grep -o '"[^"]*"'
```

**One single `grep` commands using Perl Regex** (PER)

```
grep -Po '<img[^>]*src="\K[^"]*(?=")' yourfile.html
```

**Using `ack` as a `grep`-like replacement**

```
sudo apt install ack
ack -o '<img[^>]*src="\K[^"]*(?=")' yourfile.html
```

**Downloading a web page** as proposed by [s-hunter](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2069407/s-hunter)

```
curl -s example.com/a.html | sed -En '/<img/s/.*src="([^"]*)".*/\1/p'
```

Comment: Wow, impressive! How long did it take you to come up with all that? Did you just do that from memory, or did you have to look things up?

Comment: I did from memory. After some minutes, I wondered whether it was correct. Then, I tested on my computer and saw the `sed` command was correct. However, I have not tested the `grep` ones... Should be the same for you for some obscure javascript code, isn't it?

Comment: The first command was what I needed. The others were slightly off. Still, I'm impressed. How long did it take you to become that proficient with sed? Can we become facebook friends?

Comment: Hi @javascriptninja. Thank you for compliment ;-). I am sorry I do not use facebook :-/ I hope you will help me on my web site development (lmap.org) when I will ask questions. See you. Cheers.

Comment: Thank, exactly what i needed ! (With `grep`).
Just to complete your answer, I used this following combo to download all images needed with path automatically created locally (it was for html in a csv file in my case):
`cat myfile.csv | grep -o 'src=""[^"]*"' | cut -b 5- | xargs wget -p`

Comment: Gets the images from an url:    curl www.a-web-page-url.com/ | sed -n '/<img/s/.*src="\([^"]*\)".*/\1/p'

Comment: sed: -e expression #1, char 30: invalid reference \1 on `s' command's RHS

Comment: Hi @VictorioBerra. If you use the command line proposed by s-hunter's comment, then add option `-r`. This is the correct command line: `curl www.a-web-page-url.com/ | sed -n -r '/<img/s/.*src="([^"]*)".*/\1/p'`. I am editing/improving my answer to be clear. Have fun and Happy New Year ;-)