# How to grep a link from a html modified file that starts with http and ends with .epub?

Tags: regex, sed, grep

So I have one modified html file that has some links in it, and I want to extract them (grep or similar) so I only have links that start with http://* and end with .epub, the extension).
I tried some solutions here on stackoverflow, but none seems to work as I can't seem to extract anything.
How would I go in doing this?
EDIT: The links are laid out on the file like this as well: `> http://........epub" class="..."><i` but I just want to extract everything between http and .epub, including those 2.

Comment: You say you tried something. What have you tried?

Comment: Existing solutions for regex issues with jpg, but they don't seem to work here.

Comment: Yes you said, but what are they.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9060099/getting-the-jpg-images-from-an-html-file https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32616582/extract-all-urls-that-start-with-http-or-https-and-end-with-html-from-text-file https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13611973/how-to-grep-for-a-url-in-a-file these ones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`grep -o 'http://[^ "<]*.epub' file.html` should do the trick

Comment: Doesn't result in anything, my links are http either way, not https, I don't know if it influences it. The links are laid out on the file like this as well: ` >
  http://........epub" class="..."><i ` but I just want to extract everything between http and .epub, including those 2.

Comment: Doesn't matter if https or not. But seems your addresses are not actual links, but just text. Give this one a try: `grep -Po '\bhttp://((?!http://)[^"<])+\.epub\b' file.html`

Comment: Still nothing, if it helps, they're formatted like this: http://.../download/.../filename.epub"

Comment: Well, something is off then. If not even `grep -o 'http://[^ "<]*.epub' file.html` is working (simple and tolerant), then you were either forgetting the options after `grep` or something else if off, like weird encoding. If you could post a full verbatim line of that file, that could help to find out what's going on.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/jM8ZfV0P here's a block of it, then it repeats on the whole file thousands of times, but what I'm really interested in is the http*.epub .

Comment: Hmm, my latest regex work with that for me. So I'm not sure why they don't work for you. Maybe you're invoking it incorrectly? Forgetting to specify the filename or something?

Comment: Sorted it out, it was a filesystem problem, it worked with the second comment :-) Thanks for the help!

Comment: Ah good, glad to hear ^_^